# Can I Expand "Nested" Symbolic Functions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm trying to model the effect of different filter "building blocks" on a system which is a construct based on these filters.
I would like the basic filters to be "modular", i.e. they should be "replaceable", without rewriting the construct which is based upon the basic filters.

For example, I have a system of filters G_0, G_1, which is defined in terms of some basic filters called H_0 and H_1.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
    syms z
    syms H_0(z) H_1(z)
    G_0(z)=H_0(z^(4))*H_0(z^(2))*H_0(z)
    G_1(z)=H_1(z^(4))*H_0(z^(2))*H_0(z)
```

This declares the z-domain I'd like to work in, and a construct of two filters G_0,G_1, based on the basic filters H_0,H_1.

Now, I'm trying to evaluate the construct in terms of some basic filters:

```
    H_1(z) = 1+z^-1
    H_0(z) = 1+0*z^-1
```

What I would like to get at this point is an expanded polynomial of z.
E.g. for the declarations above, I'd like to see that G_0(z)=1, and that G_1(z)=1+z^(-4).

I've tried stuff like "subs(G_0(z))", "formula(G_0(z))", "formula(subs(subs(G_0(z))))", but I keep getting result in terms of H_0 and H_1.

Any advice? Many thanks in advance.

Edit - some clarifications:

- In reality, I have 10-20 transfer functions like G_0 and G_1, so I'm trying to avoid re-declaring all of them every time I change the basic blocks H_0 and H_1. The basic blocks H_0 and H_1 would actually be of a much higher degree than they are in the example here.
- G_0 and G_1 will not change after being declared, only H_0 and H_1 will.
- `H_0(z^2)` means using z^2 as an argument for `H_0(z)`. So wherever z appears in the declaration of H_0, z^2 should be plugged in
- The desired output is a function in terms of z, not H_0 and H_1.
- A workable hack is having an m-File containing the declarations of the construct (G_0 and G_1 in this example), which is run every time H_0 and H_1 are redefined. I was wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing it, along the lines of the (non-working) code shown above.

Comment: In case it is not obvious, I'm trying to avoid feeding again the full expressions of the construct after each time the basic filters are redefined... Thanks.

Comment: i would do it without the line
    syms H_0(z) H_1(z)

no need for it since you need the output in the terms of z not H

Comment: Also - re-stressing the requirement from the second line of my question: I would like the basic filters to be "modular", i.e. they should be "replaceable", without rewriting the construct which is based upon the basic filters.
So H_0 and H_1 shouldn't be considered as "known" when I declare G_0 and G_1.

Comment: the best i can come up with is 
subs(G_1(z),[H_0(z), H_1(z)],[1+z^-1, 1+0*z^-1])  which will only exchange H_0(z) and H_1(z) not H_(z^2 or 4)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to plug into what or what you're trying to avoid (you might try showing code for the other way). And what does `H_0(z^2)` mean? I think I know what you're trying to say, but it's probably not correct mathematically as it would be the same as `H_0(z)`. You may need separate variables or a different way of representing your transfer functions. Finally, when calling `subs` you probably need to use just the name of the function (`G_0`) -  I try to explain that in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709880/2278029).

Comment: As I explained, I'm trying to model various choices of basic filters in a system which is based upon them. The declarations I've provided are simplified so that the construct is explained easily. In reality I have 10-20 declarations like G_0 and G_1, and I would like to try various options for H_0 and H_1, some of them could be polynomials of degree 20 or more.
`H_0(z^2)` means using z^2 as an argument for `H_0(z)`. So wherever **z** appears in the declaration of H_0, z^2 should be plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work quite nicely, and is very easily extendable. I redefined `H_0` to `H_1` as an example only.

```
syms z

H_1(z) = 1+z^-1;
H_0(z) = 1+0*z^-1;

G_0=@(Ha,z) Ha(z^(4))*Ha(z^(2))*Ha(z);
G_1=@(Ha,Hb,z) Hb(z^(4))*Ha(z^(2))*Ha(z);

G_0(H_0,z)
G_1(H_0,H_1,z)

H_0=@(z) H_1(z);

G_0(H_0,z)
G_1(H_0,H_1,z)
```

Comment: This way, G_0 and G_1 are based on the declaration of H_0 and H_1, only at the time they were declared.
Changing H_0 and H_1 after G_0 and G_1 are declared will not reflect these changes.

Comment: I see. I think I have figured it out, see if this code does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I also thought at some point of using anonymous functions, but I was sure there must be some way to do this using the symbolic toolbox.
I guess that's the only way to go (either that, or just re-declaring the whole thing with an m-File after each change).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a namespace issue. You can't define a symbolic expression or function in terms of arbitrary/abstract `symfun`s and then later on define these `symfun`s explicitly and be able to use them to obtain an exploit form of the original symbolic expression or function (at least not easily). Here's an example of how a symbolic function can be replaced by name:

```
syms z y(z)
x(z) = y(z);
y(z) = z^2; % Redefines y(z)
subs(x,'y(z)',y)
```

Unfortunately, this method depends on specifying the function(s) to be substituted exactly – because strings are used, Matlab sees arbitrary/abstract `symfun`s with different arguments as different functions. So the following example does not work as it returns `y(z^2)`:

```
syms z y(z)
x(z) = y(z^2); % Function of z^2 instead
y(z) = z^2;
subs(x,'y(z)',y)
```

But if the last line was changed to `subs(x,'y(z^2)',y)` it would work.

So one option might be to form strings for case, but that seems overly complex and inelegant. I think that it would make more sense to simply not explicitly (re)define your arbitrary/abstract `H_0`, `H_1`, etc. functions and instead use other variables. In terms of the simple example:

```
syms z y(z)
x(z) = y(z^2);
y_(z) = z^2; % Create new explicit symfun
subs(x,y,y_)
```

which returns `z^4`. For your code:

```
syms z H_0(z) H_1(z)
G_0(z) = H_0(z^4)*H_0(z^2)*H_0(z);
G_1(z) = H_1(z^4)*H_0(z^2)*H_0(z);

H_0_(z) = 1+0*z^-1;
H_1_(z) = 1+z^-1;
subs(G_0, {H_0, H_1}, {H_0_, H_1_})
subs(G_1, {H_0, H_1}, {H_0_, H_1_})
```

which returns

```
ans(z) =

1


ans(z) =

1/z^4 + 1
```

You can then change `H_0_` and `H_1_`, etc. at will and use `subs to evaluate`G_1`and`G_2` again.

Comment: That would be a pretty good solution for the problem, if it worked. I'm getting here:
    ans(z) =
     
    H_0(z^2)*H_0(z^4)
     
     
    ans(z) =
     
    H_0(z^2)*H_1(z^4)

(on Matlab R2012b). Which version are you using?

Comment: @user2934229: I'm using 2013b.

Comment: This may be because `subs` doesn't officially support `symfun`s. Using regular functions like @David show is probably the way to go anyways. I would never write code like my answer here myself.

Comment: OK, thanks for your time and advice. I was thinking there must be some solution for this using the symbolic toolbox.